# Give me basic idea on procedure to follow for this question :

Tags: linear-algebra

In the space R[0, 1], define the vectors f, g, and h by f (x) = x, g(x) = e x and h(x) =
e −x for 0 ≤ x ≤ 1. Use the definition of linear independence to show that the functions
f, g, and h are linearly independent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To show that $f$, $g$ and $h$ are linearly independent we have to show that:

$af(x) + bg(x) + ch(x) = 0 \Rightarrow a = b = c = 0, \forall x\in [0,1]$

so suppose $af(x) + bg(x) + ch(x) = ax + be^x + ce^{-x} = 0$

Substituting 1. $x = 0$, 2. $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and 3. $x = 1$

we get the following system of equations:

1. $b + c = 0$
2. $\frac{a}{2} + b\sqrt e + \frac{c}{\sqrt e} = 0$
3. $a + b e + \frac{c}{e} = 0$

therefore $a = b = c = 0$ is the only solution, and we are done

Comment: In the space R[0, 1], define the vectors f, g, and h by f (x) = x, g(x) = e x and h(x) = e −x for 0 ≤ x ≤ 1.????

Comment: you totally misleaded me

Comment: Sorry these vectors are actually linearly dependent. If we let $af(x) + bg(x) +ch(x)=0$ then we can find a non-zero solution, $a=1$, $b=- \frac{1}{e}$, $c=0$. Sorry if I mislead you.